# Date format on Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile

```
std = new Date("2012-06-22 00:05:00");
std_string = std.getHours() + ":" + std.getMinutes();
```

On mobile browser (Android, Blackberry 7) it show: "Nan:Nan", why?

How could I fix that?

**"2012-06-22 00:05:00"** come from a http WebService and is MYSQL datetime format

Comment: Has something to do with Javascript not liking your time format I think. I had a similar issue with JQuery datepicker dialog box. I'll try to dig though my code and see if I find what the exact solution was...

Comment: Which Android version are you running ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to create your object like this :

```
var dateWS = "2012-06-22 00:05:00";
var date = dateWS.split(" ")[0].split("-");
var time = dateWS.split(" ")[1].split(":");

var dateObj = new Date(date[0],date[1],date[2],time[0],time[1],time[2]);
var std_string = dateObj .getHours() + ":" + dateObj .getMinutes();
alert(std_string);
```

I Jsfiddled it so you can try it directly on your browser : 
http://jsfiddle.net/PyGgb/

EDIT : I made a test on my Android 2.3 and it's working :

[image]

Comment: I can't. That date come from a WebService

Comment: @user1028100: If this came from a webservice, receive the value into a variable and you can do what you have to do before using the value.   @Zakaria: The first line is unnecessary. You can replace  `dateObj` by `std` and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is '-' . Yous can use '/' instead of  '-' ..

replace your "2012-06-22 00:05:00" '-' to '/'.

```
   var temp = "2012-06-22 00:05:00".replace('-','/');
   var std = new Date(temp);
   var std_string = std.getHours() + ":" + std.getMinutes();
   alert(std_string);
```